# showing images in Laravel 8 live wire

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-livewire

I have installed laravel 8 and a fresh install of LiveWire authentication scaffolding but when I add an image it does not show and if I try to load the image in aq new tab it redirects to index page

I have added the image as follows

```
<img src="{{asset( Auth::user()->profile_photo_url) }}" />
```

What could I be doing wrong or what could I be missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## The quick answer

You don't have to use `asset()` to display the image, you have the full image URL readily available in that property. It should therefor simply be

```html
<img src="{{ auth()->user()->profile_photo_url }}" />
```

## The long answer

If you'll find the source for that `profile_photo_url` attribute, which can be found in the `Laravel\Jetstream\HasProfilePhoto` trait, you'll see that its defined as

```
/**
 * Get the URL to the user's profile photo.
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getProfilePhotoUrlAttribute()
{
    return $this->profile_photo_path
                ? Storage::disk($this->profilePhotoDisk())->url($this->profile_photo_path)
                : $this->defaultProfilePhotoUrl();
}
```

This means that if there is a profile photo, fetch the URL of the disk where profile photos are defined - otherwise, get the default one (which is using `ui-avatars.com`).

So this means we'll have to learn about the `Storage::disk(..)->url(..)` methods, and figure out what disk we're using. The default disk is the public one (you can take my word for it, or check the `profilePhotoDisk()` method in the same trait).

So we now know that the photo will be stored in the storage, under the public disk. Next, we need to figure out what the [`url()`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/filesystem#file-urls) method does. It essentially generates the path to the actual image, all ready to use in an image-soruce tag. Which in turn means that you don't need to run the `profile_photo_url` property through the `asset()` method! Another reason for this is that you won't get the actual image if the source is external, i.e. the default image from `ui-avatars.com`.

Comment: Well I noticed an error in the app url and changed it to http://127.0.0.1:8000/ but that still wont show the image